# Unwrapping a custom list type

Tags: f#

If I have the following:

```
type StringList = StringList of string list
let sl = StringList [ "Hello, "; "World" ]
let length = List.length sl
```

then the following compiler error is thrown:

```
This expression was expected to have type 'a list but here has type StringList
```

My understanding is that `StringList` is an `option` "wrapping" `string list`, so how can I "unwrap" it such that I can call `List` methods on it?

Comment: _Context: just started learning F#._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `StringList` type is defining a new type that is a wrapper over `string list`. The functions that would work on `string list` do not work on your wrapper, because they do not know anything about it.

You could define `StringList` as a type alias - so rather than defining a new type, it is just a convenient name for the same thing:

```
type StringList = string list
let sl : StringList = [ "Hello, "; "World" ]
let length = List.length sl
```

The other option is to extract the `string list` value before calling `List.length`:

```
type StringList = StringList of string list

let stringListlength (StringList(slData)) = 
    List.length slData

let sl = StringList [ "Hello, "; "World" ]
stringListlength sl
```

In the first approach, you are just defining a name, but the compiler will not do any checks on it, so it is only useful if you want to use the name in type annotations (for example) to make them readable.

In the second approach, you are really defining a new type, so you ensure that everyone working with `StringList` will use the functions you define or working with it.

It is hard to say what is a good approach here, because `StringList` is not very good example - it does not really convey any additional information over `string list`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am doing the wrapping to get type safety so your second option is exactly what I was missing. Thank you very much!